# Replacing values in one array/list by index of another array/list

Tags: arrays, indexing, replace

I have a seemingly simple problem which I cannot seem to solve without doing a loop. (I am dealing with very large arrays)

Lets say for simplicity sake that I have a sorted array and an unsorted array of a different dimension such as:
 x=np.array([511,512,513]) and
 y=np.array([512,512,513,511,511]).
I want a fast function that replaces y with the index positions given in  the sorted min to max array x.
Answer should be output =np.array([1,1,2,0,0])

I would love to be able to do this in one or two steps. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Convert the sorted array so that the index is the value and value is the position (hashmap?). i.e. `[ 511 => 0, 512 => 1, 513 => 2]` The lookup from the unsorted array will be fast as you are looking up in the 'sorted array' by key.

Comment: Thanks that worked. This is what I used:   dictionary=dict(zip(x,z)) where z was the index array [0,1,2]. Then a list comprehension l=[dicitonary[i] for i in unsortedlist]. Mucho fast.

Answer (score 1):

[`searchsorted()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) does exactly what you want:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.array([511,512,513])
y=np.array([512,512,513,511,511])
np.searchsorted(x, y) #  array([1, 1, 2, 0, 0])
```